# DLRS Where Date 1 = Date 2 Error (expected colon received text)

Tags: soql, dlrs

I would like to have DLRS run a count on child records through a lookup. The where clause for counting is to compare a DATE field on the Lookup Parent to a Date/Time field on the Lookup Child.

My Where clause is written as follows:

`CustomObjectParent__c.Datefield__c = (DATEVALUE(CustomObjectChild__c.Date_time__c))`

It does not allow it and provides the following error:

> Error: Relationship Criteria 'CustomObjectParent__c.Datefield__c =
>   (DATEVALUE(CustomObjectChild__c.Date_time__c))' is not valid, see SOQL
>   documentation
>   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm,
>   error is 'expecting a colon, found '(''

Can I only use EQUALS with a field and an argument? eg `FIELD__c = 25`.

How else can I get the answer I need so that the DLRS roll-up summary only chooses children with a date/time field of the same date as the parent date field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOQL doesn't currently support comparing two fields, but it's [coming soon](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0) (Safe Harbor applies). For now, if you want something like that to work, you need to create a custom formula, such as:

```
Same Parent Date (Checkbox) =
  SomeDate__c = Parent__r.SomeDate__c
```

And from there, in DLRS, you would say something like:

```
Same_Parent_Date__c = true
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this particular DLRS rollup will not work in Realtime mode and has to be run Scheduled.